# How to give su permission to a executable in android?

Tags: android, root

I have an executable which needs `su` permission to run on android. I have to manually give the permission on command prompt and then run the app. Is there any way to give the permission internally so that I don't have to follow the steps.

Comment: I dont think you can do it without root.

Comment: What do you mean by "executable"? And what for do you need the permission?

Comment: @Mighter, it is an application. it runs on command prompt.

Comment: @Kedarnath, the phone is not rooted. I need to find a workaround for a non rooted phone.

Comment: @Sid what kind of workaround? The phone is either rooted or no. To root the device you have to follow manual steps, which are different from vendor to vendor.
If the phone is not rooted, there's no su binary.

Comment: @Mighter is there any way to get the su binary without rooting the phone?

Comment: @mighter, i have rooted the phone. i want to make changes in init.rc or init.target.rc

Comment: @Sid then remount the filesystem as writable and make the changes.

Comment: @Mighter, i did sudo mount -o remount,rw /system but it didn't work!

Comment: @Sid please provide the stack traces, log messages and a detailed description of what didn't work.

Comment: @Mighter, can you provide me the steps as to how to remount the filesystem as writeable.I may be doing something wrong here!

Comment: @Sid this has been discussed many times on SO. Search for related questions, try something. If it doesn't work - post relevant source code, environment and stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

### This will help you:

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Refer: [Check it](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/)

### Permission is:

```
android.permission.FACTORY_TEST
```